# How to correctly decode result of InternetReadFile in Delphi

Tags: delphi, pointers, utf-8, wininet

I'm making a HTTP call to my own controlled server, which returns a utf8 encoded string, in this case "1". The request is successful, but I get a broken (chinese) character in the `ContentChunk` string: 0x1031 - the ascii codepoint for "1". I'm suspecting an error in the pointer stuff but can't get to to just return "1" as string.

I stripped off irrelevant code and exception handling from the code:

```
uses
  WinInet, ...;
var
  NetHandle: HINTERNET;
  UrlHandle: HINTERNET;
  Buffer: array[0..4095] of AnsiChar;
  BytesInChunk: Cardinal;
  ContentChunk: String;
begin
  NetHandle := InternetOpen(PChar('user agent...'), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  UrlHandle := InternetOpenURL(NetHandle, PChar(FURL), nil, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
  InternetReadFile(UrlHandle, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BytesInChunk);
  SetString(ContentChunk, PChar(@Buffer[0]), BytesInChunk);
  ...
```

*Edit*: Delphi v10.3 / Windows 10 v1809

Comment: Use [UTF8ToString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.UTF8ToString) instead of `SetString`.

Comment: @zed or change `ContentChunk` to `UTF8String`, then `SetString` will work after changing `PChar` to `PAnsiChar`

Comment: `UTF8ToString()` doubled the single character from the response for some reason. `SetString()` with an UTF8String worked - thanks a lot!

Comment: `UTF8ToString()` works too. Try this: `Buffer[BytesInChunk] := #0;` then `ContentChunk := UTF8ToString(PAnsiChar(Buffer));`

Comment: Sounds logical: Buffer is an array, not null-terminated, so you add a null onto the end, and the additonal character is gone. Why do I think the compiler should have warned me about that non-null-terminated array?